# Vectorization of indexing a 2d array with an array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I can index a 2d array with a vector in C as follows:

```
int main()
{
double mat[5][3] = {{5.5,2.1,1.9},
                    {6.5,7.0,8.8},
                    {5.4,3.1,8.9},
                    {9.0,0.1,2.4},
                    {5.9,8.0,0.7}};
int in[4] = {3,4,2,1};
double smat[4][3];
int i,j;

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
for(j=0;j<3;j++)
{
{
    smat[i][j] = mat[in[i]][j];
}
}

printf("%.1f\n",smat[1][0]); //mat[4][0]=5.9
printf("%.1f\n",smat[0][2]); //mat[3][2]=2.4
printf("%.1f\n",smat[3][1]); //mat[1][1]=7.0

return 0;
}
```

The code successfully returns:

```
5.9
2.4
7.0
```

Question: Can we vectorize the two for-loop operation in C, not using the loops?

Comment: What do you mean by "vectorize"? Keep in mind that C isn't MATLAB.

Comment: Check the generated assembly, maybe your compiler already vectorizes it.

Comment: @Park: How to check it? I compile it by typing "cl mycode.c" using Intel Parallel Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Example which use one `for`-loop operation in C (use function `memcpy()`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

double mat[5][3] = {{5.5,2.1,1.9},
                    {6.5,7.0,8.8},
                    {5.4,3.1,8.9},
                    {9.0,0.1,2.4},
                    {5.9,8.0,0.7}};
int in[4] = {3,4,2,1};
double smat[4][3];

void main()
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        memcpy(smat[i], mat[in[i]], sizeof(double)*3);

    printf("%.1f\n",smat[1][0]); //mat[4][0]=5.9
    printf("%.1f\n",smat[0][2]); //mat[3][2]=2.4
    printf("%.1f\n",smat[3][1]); //mat[1][1]=7.0
}
```

(If that's what you mean.)